# Why they use "99" for their number format in hayate the movie manga ver?

Tags: hayate-no-gotoku

*Hayate No Gotoku* series have a move, *Hayate no gotoku: Heaven is a place on Earth*. The movie also got adapted into a manga version.

What make the manga version of Hayate movie interesting is the title. It was written in the cover:

***Hayate No Gotoku: Vol 99***

Why did they used "99" as their number format for only this tankoubon ?

Is there any reason behind it ?

[Hayate No Gotoku: Volume 99 Wiki](http://hayatenogotoku.wikia.com/wiki/Hayate_no_Gotoku!_Volume_99)

Comment: They also produced [the special BD for the movie with title "+99"](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%8A%87%E5%A0%B4%E7%89%88%E3%83%8F%E3%83%A4%E3%83%86%E3%81%AE%E3%81%94%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8F%EF%BC%81HEAVEN-PLACE-EARTH-%EF%BC%8B99%E3%80%88%E5%88%9D%E5%9B%9E%E9%99%90%E5%AE%9A%E7%89%88%E3%80%89-Blu-ray/dp/B0065UIS7Q) for having bonus contents...

Comment: First time i heard that. i only know the manga versiin that have this number. Thanks @AkiTanaka